# How do you create a constraint on parent tables that also constrains the child tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I am not sure how to phrase the question so I'll illustrate the tables and the explain what I want to achieve.

```
-- static table of the entity classes supported by the application
create table entity_type (
  id   integer     not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(30) not null,

  primary key(id)
);

-- static table of statuses supported by the application
create table entity_status (    
  id   integer     not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(30) not null,

  primary key(id)
);

-- table of valid combinations 
create table entity_type_entity_status_link (    
  entity_type_id   integer not null,
  entity_status_id integer not null,

  unique key(entity_type_id, entity_status_id),
  foreign key(entity_type_id) references entity_type(id),
  foreign key(entity_status_id) references entity_status(id),
);

-- The tables where user types and statuses are defined
create table user_type (    
  id             integer     not null auto_increment,
  name           varchar(30) not null,

  entity_type_id integer not null,
  primary key(id),
  foreign key(entity_type_id) references entity_type(id)
);

create table user_status (    
  id             integer     not null auto_increment,
  name           varchar(30) not null,

  entity_status_id integer not null,
  primary key(id),
  foreign key(entity_status_id) references entity_status(id)
);

-- table of valid pairs
create table user_type_user_status_link (    
  user_type_id   integer not null,
  user_status_id integer not null,

  unique key(user_type_id, user_status_id),
  foreign key(user_type_id) references user_type(id),
  foreign key(user_status_id) references user_status(id),
);
```

The basic premise behind these tables is that the system supports core types and statuses and the user is able to create their own user types and statues that derive from these.

The question I have is that I cannot see a way of creating any database constraints on the user_type_user_status_link table to ensure that the you cannot insert a file_type - file_status pair where the parent entity_type - entity_status is itself not valid. Or is this something that would have to be done with triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The basic premise behind these tables is that the system supports core
>   types and statuses and the user is able to create their own user types
>   and statues that derive from these.

Although that sounds like a laudable goal on the surface, the effect is to delegate database design to your users. Database design, because the effect of your desire to set foreign key references to a subset of the rows in `entity_type_entity_status_link` means each of those subsets is a defacto, unnamed table.

This approach never ends well.

What you've developed is the "One True Lookup Table". Google that for a host of reasons why OTLT is an anti-pattern.

The best solution is to model real things in your tables. (*Entity* isn't a real thing. It's an abstraction of a real thing.) Something along the lines of either

```
create table file_status (
  file_status varchar(30) primary key
);
```

or

```
create table file_status (
  file_status_id integer primary key,
  file_status varchar(30) not null unique
);
```

would work well for file statuses.

In the case of the second one, you can set a foreign key reference to either the id number (saves space, requires an additional join) or to the status text (takes more space, eliminates a join). Note that you need the unique constraint on the status text; your original design allows the user to enter the same text multiple times. (You could end up with 30 rows where `entity_type.name` is 'File'.

Comment: Catcall is quite right and normally I would avoid OTLT and EAV like the plague. In this instance though we are using Hibernate as the ORM and the user has a number of pre-defined Java classes (like INVOICE and PURCHASE_ORDER). We allow user to further categorise instances of these entities with user defined  fileType and fileStatus properties. However for project accounting reasons we need to be able to classify the user defined instances into our core classes and statuses hence the indirection.

Comment: Catcalls' answer has helped to remind me that the pursuit of 'flexibility' has resulted in us falling into the EAV trap. I think we need to recconsider our design thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use triggers for that.
MySQL does not support constraints of the form that will prevent what you want.